# Showing that a specific stochastic process is a martingale.

Tags: solution-verification, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $ X = (X_n, n \in \Bbb N_0)$ be a stochastic process with state space $\Bbb N_0$, with unitary mean value for each $n \geqslant 1$, with independent increments and such that $P(X_0 = 0) = 1.$ I wish to prove that $X$ is a martingale.

**My attempt.** We have that

$$ E(X_n) = 1, \quad \text{ for all } n \geqslant 1 $$

and, on the other hand, we also have that

$$ E(X_0) = P(X_0 = 0) \cdot 0 = 1 \cdot 0 =0 . $$

Hence, we conclude that $E(|X_n|) = E(X_n) < \infty$ for all $n \in \Bbb N_0$. Thus, if we wish to show that $X$ is a martingale, all we have to do is to show that $X$ satisfies the following property:

$$ E(X_{t_{n+1}} \, \, | \, \, X_{t_0} = x_0, \dots,X_{t_n} = x_n) = x_n, \quad \forall n \in \Bbb N, \, \forall t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_{n+1} \in \Bbb N_0, \, \forall x_0,\dots,x_{n+1} \in \Bbb N_0.   $$

With this in mind, I elaborated the following:

$$ E(X_{t_{n+1}} \, \, | \, \, X_{t_0} = x_0, X_{t_1} = x_1, \dots,X_{t_n} = x_n) = E(X_{t_{n+1}} \, \, | \, \, X_{t_0} = x_0, X_{t_1} - X_{t_0} = x_1-x_0, \dots,X_{t_n} - X_{t_{n-1}} = x_n - x_{n-1})  $$

Now, note that $X_{t_{n+1}} = X_{t_{n+1}} - X_{t_n} + X_{t_n}$ and thus we can write

$$ E(X_{t_{n+1}} \, \, | \, \, X_{t_0} = x_0, X_{t_1} - X_{t_0} = x_1-x_0, \dots,X_{t_n} - X_{t_{n-1}} = x_n - x_{n-1}) $$

$$ =  E(X_{t_{n+1}} - X_{t_n} \, \, | \, \, X_{t_0} = x_0, X_{t_1} - X_{t_0} = x_1-x_0, \dots,X_{t_n} - X_{t_{n-1}} = x_n - x_{n-1}) $$

$$ + E(X_{t_n} \, \, | \, \, X_{t_0} = x_0, X_{t_1} - X_{t_0} = x_1-x_0, \dots,X_{t_n} - X_{t_{n-1}} = x_n - x_{n-1}).$$

Now, we know that $X$ has independent increments and thus $X_{t_1} - X_{t_0},\dots,X_{t_{n+1}} - X_{t_n}$ are independent variables and so we **almost** can  "forget" the conditionality on the first mean value. Basically, I am having a hard time dealing with $X_{t_0},$ because without it I think I would be able to solve this.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much simpler than that. Let $m>n$ and note that
\begin{align}
E(X_m | \mathcal{F}_n ) &= E(X_n + (X_m-X_n)| \mathcal{F}_n) \\
&= X_n + E( X_m-X_n| \mathcal{F}_n) \\
&= X_n + E( X_m-X_n) \\
&= X_n
\end{align}
Where the third line is due to the independence of increments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jose. I didn't understand some things: what do you mean by $\mathcal F_n$ ? And why is $E(X_n | \mathcal F_n) = X_n $ ?

Comment: You can think of $\mathcal{F}_n$ as the information up to time $n$. You can replace it with $X_0, \ldots , X_n$. Since at time $n$ you already know the state of $X_n$, the conditional expectation is itself.

Comment: Thanks. That was a perfect comment amid my questions. I just have one more followup question: I don't understand how your definition of a martingale coincides with mine: you seem to take $t_0 = 0, t_1 = 1, \dots , t_n = n$ (then you take $m>n$ which is fine since I take $t_{n+1} > t_n$). Aren't you losing any kind of generality by doing this designation ? I am asking this because these variables $t_i$ must be increasing but not necessarily spaced by one unit, according to my definition.

Comment: No generality is lost @xyz

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I can't understand how. Furthermore, could you also assume that $m = n+1$, without loss of generality?

Comment: @xyz you can, provided that $E(X_{n+1}|F_n) = X_n$ holds for all $n$

Comment: Thanks. I have one final question before accepting the answer: what exactly is the reasoning behind the step $ E(X_m - X_n \, | \, \mathcal F_n) = E(X_m - X_n) ? $ I know that since $X$ has independent increments we have that $X_1 - X_0, X_2 - X_1, \dots, X_n - X_{n-1}, X_{m} - X_n$ are independent and thus we can write $$ E(X_m - X_n \, | \, \mathcal F_n ) = E (X_m - X_n \, | \, X_0, \dots, X_n) = E(X_m - X_n \, | \, X_0, X_1 - X_0, \dots, X_n - X_{n-1}).$$ But how do we guarantee that $X_0$ is also independent of every other variable in cause?

Comment: @xyz $X_0$ is a constant, so it's independent from increments. You may check this using the definition of independence.